# How to stop/disable 'python-crontab' from automatically converting certain cron values to aliases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I'm using `'python-crontab'` library to programmatically edit crontab. There are other cron commands present in the same file, which have values `'0 * * * *'` and `'0 0 * * *'`.

The issue I've been facing is, Whenever I edit CRON programmatically to add or remove a line using the python package, it automatically converts

`'0 * * * *'` to `'@hourly'` and

`'0 0 * * *'` to `'@daily'`

in previously existing CRON lines.

This causes the CRON to stop as the CRON in the machine does not support aliases such as above.

How do I disable the package from automatically converting the CRON patterns into aliases ? Or alternatively, how do I enable alias support in CRON configuration ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I went through the github repo, found a dictionary and a list.

```
SPECIALS = {"reboot":   '@reboot',
            "hourly":   '0 * * * *',
            "daily":    '0 0 * * *',
            "weekly":   '0 0 * * 0',
            "monthly":  '0 0 1 * *',
            "yearly":   '0 0 1 1 *',
            "annually": '0 0 1 1 *',
            "midnight": '0 0 * * *'}

SPECIAL_IGNORE = ['midnight', 'annually']
```

Edited the SPECIAL_IGNORE to below

```
SPECIAL_IGNORE = ['midnight', 'annually', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly']
```

The function render() uses a flag 'specials' which is set to True by Default. I set it to 'False' to disable conversion of CRON patterns to Aliases. It has worked so far.